# Find possible values

Tags: formula, z3, smt, z3py

I want to verify a formula of the form:

```
Exists p . ForAll x != 0 . f(x, p) > 0 and g(x, p) < 0
```

All variables are reals.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279196/nonzero-vector-in-quantifier), I add this list to the solver:

```
[ForAll([x0, x1],
    Implies(Or(x0 != 0, x1 != 0),
        And(P0*x0*x0 + P1*x0*x1 + P2*x0*x1 + P3*x1*x1 > 0,
            -2*P0*x0*x1 + P1*x0*x0 - P1*x0*x1 - P1*x1*x1 + P2*x0*x0 - P2*x0*x1 - P2*x1*x1 + 2*P3*x0*x1 - 2*P3*x1*x1 < 0
            )
        )
    )
]
```

The solver with the above formula returns `unsat`. A possible solution is for `P` to be `[[1.5, -0.5], [-0.5, 1]]` and in fact, by substituting those values, the formula is satisfied:

```
And(3/2*x0*x0 - 1*x0*x1 + x1*x1 > 0,
    -1*x0*x0 - 1*x1*x1 < 0)
```

Is there a way to actually compute such a `p`? If it's hard for z3, is there any alternative for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'Exists' followed by 'Forall', then you are saying that the formula should be true for every such `x0`, `x1`. And Z3 is telling you that is simply not the case.

If you are interested in finding one such `P`, and corresponding `x` values, simply drop the quantification and make everything a top-level variable:

```py
from z3 import *

def f(x0, x1, P0, P1, P2, P3):
    return P0*x0*x0 + P1*x0*x1 + P2*x0*x1 + P3*x1*x1

def g(x0, x1, P0, P1, P2, P3):
    return -2*P0*x0*x1 + P1*x0*x0 - P1*x0*x1 - P1*x1*x1 + P2*x0*x0 - P2*x0*x1 - P2*x1*x1 + 2*P3*x0*x1 - 2*P3*x1*x1

p0, p1, p2, p3  = Reals('p0 p1 p2 p3')

x0, x1 = Reals('x0 x1')
fmls = [Implies(Or(x0 != 0, x1 != 0), And(f(x0, x1, p0, p1, p2, p3) > 0, g(x0, x1, p0, p1, p2, p3) < 0))]

while True:
    s = Solver()
    s.add(fmls)
    res = s.check()
    print res
    if res == sat:
        m = s.model()
        print m
        fmls += [Or(p0 != m[p0], p1 != m[p1])]
    else:
       print "giving up"
       break
```

When I run this, I get:

```
sat
[x0 = 1/8, p0 = -1/2, p1 = -1/2, x1 = 1/2, p2 = 1, p3 = 1]
```

and many others; which is I believe what you're after.

Note that you can also do some programming to get rid of the existential quantification depending on where you are; i.e., start with the quantified version, if you get an `unsat`, then switch to a new solver and use the unquantified version to automate this process. Of course, this is just programming and doesn't really have anything to do with z3 at this point.

Comment: I'm really interested in finding a `P` for which all nonzero reals satisfy the formula; that `P` exists, because the one in the first post satisfy the formula for all nonzero reals

Comment: Also, when you say: "And Z3 is telling you that is simply not the case", then Z3 is wrong, because of that example. And introducing the values makes Z3's result be `sat`

Comment: @nyuw I didn't study the expression, but if you do believe Z3 is wrong, then that would be a rather serious bug that should be reported. (This is a soundness issue, and developers should know about it!) I'd encourage you to report it at their issue tracker: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: @nyuw I've since looked at the expressions in more detail, and I think you're right that Z3 seems to be saying `unsat` for no good reason. Unless there's some other gotcha, this might very well be a bug. Please report this at their issues page. (Or I can do the same, let me know.)

Comment: I've created an issue; please let me know if you think it's properly written. I also wasn't exactly sure why I had to drop the `Exists` quantifier at the beginning (ref. my previous question); but even by adding it again, some of the values for `P` are wrong (?) or they don't work if hard coded (as I said in the issue). Let me know

Comment: @nyuw The bug is now fixed: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1637 If you do a build off of github (or wait for the nightly builds to come out), I think you'll find it now works as expected.

Comment: @nyuw It would be good to close the bug (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1637) if this is all working as expected now.

Comment: I just wanted to test it a bit more. Thank you so much :)